# Adding objects to a deep array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've just started building a little application using MongoDB and can't seem to find any examples where I can add objects to a deep array that I can then find on an individual basis.

Let me illustrate by the following set of steps I take as well as the code I've written.

I create a simple object in MongoDB like so:

```
testing = { name: "s1", children: [] };
db.data.save(testing);
```

When I query it everything looks nice and simple still:

```
db.data.find();
```

Which outputs:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f36121082b4c129cfce3901"), 
  "name" : "s1",
  "children" : [ ] 
}
```

However, after I update the "children" array by "pushing" an object into it, I get into **all sorts** of problems.

First the update command that I run:

```
db.data.update({ name:"s1" },{ 
  $push: {
    children: { name:"r1" }
  }
});
```

Then when I query the DB:

```
db.data.find({
  children: { name: "r1" }
});
```

Results in:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f36121082b4c129cfce3901"), 
  "children" : [ { "name" : "r1" } ], 
  "name" : "s1" 
}
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me, since I would have **expected** the following:

```
{ 
  "name": "r1"
}
```

Is there a better way of inserting data into MongoDB so that when I run queries I extract individual objects rather than the entire tree? Or perhaps a better way of writing the "find" query?

Answer (score 1):

By default mongodb find retrieve all the fields(like `* from` in sql). You can extract the particular field by specifying the field name
.

```
  db.data.find({  "children.name": "r1" },'children.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect ot to return only part of a document?  It returns the whole document unless you tell it which fields you want to explicitly include or exclude.  See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Comment: Mainly due to the way JSON/BSON objects work, especially in Arrays. If one says "find me a specific comment for a given blog post", it doesn't really make sense to return the blog post + all other comments, but instead the comment object only. I have found a resource on the MongoDB documentation website which mentions different ways of structuring trees, but haven't found anything useful to go on just yet.

Comment: Use the feature in the link I listed to get the fields you want.  There are many more cases where you want more than the one found field returned than there are cases where you would only want one small bit of the document returned in response to a search.